# Play sound every 6-10 seconds

Tags: java, android

How do you repeat a sound every 6-10 seconds, meaning a random interval between 6 and 10? So the sound plays 6, then 7, 6, 10, etc? So far I have this, which works how I want and plays the sound “once” and changes the button on the screen. However to play the sound again i must click the button to “stop” then click again to “go”. I want to Hit then button and have the sound repeat every 6-10 seconds until you hit the stop button...

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.whistle);
    Timer soundTimer = new Timer();

    Random r = new Random();


    //Button related to play btn
    final Button startStopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startstopbutton);
    startStopButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (startStopButton.getText().equals("Start")) {
                //start the sound


                //change button color and text
                startStopButton.setText("Stop");
                startStopButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                myMediaPlayer.start();



            } else  {
                //stop whistle

                //change button color and text
                startStopButton.setText("Start");
                startStopButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);




            }


        }
    });

}
```

Comment: You can create a `TimerTask` to play the media and schedule a `Timer` with a random delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener to accomplish this, whenever the playback completes get a random number between 6 and 10 and post a runnable to start playback again after the calculated random time.

Here is an example of doing this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button button1;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
private final Random mRandom = new Random();
int delayMillis;
Handler handler;
Runnable runnable;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mediaPlayer.start();

        }
    };
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toggleMediaPlayer();

        }
    });
}

private void toggleMediaPlayer(){
    if(mediaPlayer != null){
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer=null;
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }else{
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hangouts_incoming_call);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();

            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                delayMillis = 1000 * mRandom.nextInt(5) + 6;
                handler.postDelayed(runnable,delayMillis);
            }
        });

    }
}}
```

Hope This helps .

Comment: Why would you want to keep creating the MediaPlayer over and over again?

Comment: Yes, you can avoid creating the MediaPlayer over and over, just keep in mind to call mediaPlayer.prepare() before starting the media player again after you stop it by mediaPlayer.stop()

Answer (score 1):

You can get a random number between 6 and 10 like this:

```
int max = 10;
int min = 6;
int randomNum = new Random().nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
int seconds = randomNum * 1000;
```

Here is an example to play a sound every 6 to 10 seconds:

```
private final Random mRandom = new Random();

private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

private boolean mKeepPlaying = true;

private void playMySound() {
    if (mPlayer == null) {
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.whistle);
    }
    int delayMillis = 1000 * mRandom.nextInt(5) + 6; // random number between 6 and 10
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (isFinishing()) {
                // Check if the Activity is finishing.
                return;
            }
            mPlayer.start();
            if (mKeepPlaying) {
                // play the sound again in 6 to 10 seconds
                playMySound();
            }
        }
    }, delayMillis);
}
```

Just call `playMySound();` in `onCreate(Bundle)` and toggle `mKeepPlaying` when you want to stop.